mjs files from dependency are not being handled by babel or webpack
At my job we have a React library of components. One of those components use pdfjs-dist. We just updated the version of pdfjs-dist to fix an audit issue. The new version of pdfjs-dist now uses files with the .mjs extension. This is my first encounter with mjs files. Even though I have been trying to read up on them I am still not sure how best to handle them.
Our component library when published is transpiled first using Babel. Then in our apps we use those components and use webpack and babel-loader to create the final artifacts.
In all cases we use import rather than require. After the first transpilation for the library the imports go from this
import isNil from 'lodash/isNil';

to this
var _isNil = _interopRequireDefault(require("lodash/isNil"));

However Babel transforms this
import { getDocument } from 'pdfjs-dist';

const loadingTask = getDocument({ data: file.data });

to this
var _pdfjsDist = require("pdfjs-dist");

var loadingTask = (0, _pdfjsDist.getDocument)({
  data: file.data
});

These same two examples after webpack is done look like this
var _isNil = _interopRequireDefault(__webpack_require__(/*! lodash/isNil */ \"./node_modules/lodash/isNil.js\"));

var _pdfjsDist = __webpack_require__(/*! pdfjs-dist */ \"./node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.mjs\");

var loadingTask = (0, _pdfjsDist.getDocument)({data: file.data});

Somewhere along the way something is broken because I am now getting this.
ERROR in ./node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.mjs 18907:24-31 Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'process/browser' in '\~/source/local/node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build' Did you mean 'browser.js'? BREAKING CHANGE: The request 'process/browser' failed to resolve only because it was resolved as fully specified (probably because the origin is strict EcmaScript Module, e. g. a module with javascript mimetype, a '\*.mjs' file, or a '\*.js' file where the package.json contains '"type": "module"'). The extension in the request is mandatory for it to be fully specified. Add the extension to the request. Did you miss the leading dot in 'resolve.extensions'? Did you mean '\[".\*",".js",".jsx",".css",".scss"\]' instead of '\["\*",".js",".jsx",".css",".scss"\]'?

and this
`ERROR in ./node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.mjs Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'module') TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'module')`

I did find that if I added this to webpack
{
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.m?js/,
        resolve: {
          fullySpecified: false,
        },
      },
    ],
    // ... Other config
  },
  // ... Other config
}

Then the application runs. However when I get to the part where the component loads I get this error off the browser console.
Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _pdfjsDist.getDocument) is not a function

I don't want to inundate this post with a bunch of useless information so if there is anything that you feel I could add which might be helpful please let me know. For now I will add my Babel config for the component library and the webpack for one of our apps.
module.exports = {
  env: {
    development: {
      compact: false,
    },
  },
  presets: [
    '@babel/env',
    '@babel/react',
  ],
  plugins: [
    '@babel/plugin-transform-runtime',
    'babel-plugin-inline-import',
    ['babel-plugin-transform-remove-imports', {
      'test': '\\.(scss|css)$'
    }],
    ['inline-react-svg', {
      svgo: false,
    }],
  ],
  sourceMaps: 'inline',
};

Here is also our webpack
./webpack.common.js
require('dotenv').config();

const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const reduce = require('lodash/reduce');
const merge = require('lodash/merge');
const pick = require('lodash/pick');

const commonPaths = require('./paths');

const mapAliases = (dependencies, folder) =>
    reduce(
        dependencies,
        (acc, dependency) => ({
            [dependency]: path.resolve(`${folder}/${dependency}`),
            ...acc,
        }),
        {},
    );

const env = pick(process.env ?? {}, [
    'BASE_URL_OVERRIDE',
    'REDIRECT_BACK_TO_APP',
    'DASHBOARD_URL',
    'NODE_ENV',
]);

module.exports = envOverrides => {
    const environmentVars = JSON.stringify(
        envOverrides ? merge({}, env, envOverrides) : env,
    );

    return {
        entry: commonPaths.entryPath,
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.m?js/,
                    resolve: {
                        fullySpecified: false,
                    },
                },
                {
                    test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                    // test: /\.(js|jsx|mjs)$/,
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    include: [commonPaths.devRoot],
                },
                {
                    test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: 'file-loader',
                            options: {
                                outputPath: commonPaths.imagesFolder,
                            },
                        },
                    ],
                },
                {
                    test: /\.(woff2|ttf|woff|eot)$/,
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: 'file-loader',
                            options: {
                                outputPath: commonPaths.fontsFolder,
                            },
                        },
                    ],
                },
            ],
        },
        resolve: {
            modules: ['node_modules', 'src', commonPaths.webAppSrc],
            extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx', '.css', '.scss'],
            alias: mapAliases(
                [
                    'react',
                    'react-dom',
                    'react-router-dom',
                    'fluxible',
                    'fluxible-addons-react',
                    'history',
                ],
                './node_modules',
            ),
            fallback: {
                buffer: require.resolve('buffer'),
                crypto: require.resolve('crypto-browserify'),
                process: require.resolve('process/browser'),
                stream: require.resolve('stream-browserify'),
                util: require.resolve('util'),
            },
        },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.DefinePlugin({
                'process.env': environmentVars,
            }),
            new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
                process: 'process/browser',
            }),
            new webpack.ProgressPlugin(),
            new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                template: commonPaths.templatePath,
                scriptLoading: 'defer',
            }),
        ],
    };
};

./webpack.development.js
const webpack = require('webpack');
const { merge } = require('webpack-merge');
const portFinder = require('portfinder');
const set = require('lodash/set');
const common = require('./webpack.common');
const commonPaths = require('./paths');

const config = {
    mode: 'development',
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        path: commonPaths.outputPath,
        chunkFilename: '[name].js',
        publicPath: '/',
    },
    devtool: 'eval-source-map',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(css|scss)$/,
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: true,
                            modules: {
                                localIdentName: '[local]',
                                exportLocalsConvention: 'camelCase',
                            },
                        },
                    },
                    'sass-loader',
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                use: ['source-map-loader'],
                enforce: 'pre',
                exclude: /react-hot-loader/,
            },
        ],
    },
    target: 'web',
    devServer: {
        static: commonPaths.outputPath,
        allowedHosts: 'all',
        compress: true,
        hot: true,
        historyApiFallback: true,
        open: true,
        host: process.env.HOST || 'localhost',
        client: {
            overlay: false,
        },
    },
    plugins: [new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()],
};

module.exports = () =>
    portFinder
        .getPortPromise({
            port: process.env.PORT || 8080,
        })
        .catch(() => '8080')
        .then(port => {
            set(config, 'devServer.port', port);
            return merge(common(), config);
        });


Two things to try, the latter probably being the easiest and requiring less overall changes. Either use modules: false in the babel config’s env preset to provide a full esm version of the component library and then let the apps webpack build do the rest, or use a dynamic import() when loading pdfjs.
